# Dreamweaver Live and Safari not receiving changes to HTML

Tags: safari, dreamweaver

My site is working well in all major browsers but for some reason my most recent changes aren't updating in Dreamweaver Live view or Safari.
[image]

With Live view turned off, the "All" is removed from "Upcoming Sessions" as it should be. Similarly, the "All" shows up in Safari but not in any other browser.

I deleted my Dreamweaver cache as well as my Safari cache, but to no avail.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Stupid cookies ;)